# logcat error while establishing connection with remote server

Tags: android

After trying out some the solutions provided, I am able to retrieve response from server but still not able to display the JSON array I'm receiving and app is crashing,please help me out :

Logcat error

```
07-07 11:12:09.500: E/AndroidRuntime(1829): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-07 11:12:09.500: E/AndroidRuntime(1829): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.g2k/com.example.g2k.HotelSearch}: java.lang.NullPointerException: println needs a message
07-07 11:12:09.500: E/AndroidRuntime(1829):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
07-07 11:12:09.500: E/AndroidRuntime(1829):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
07-07 11:12:09.500: E/AndroidRuntime(1829):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
07-07 11:12:09.500: E/AndroidRuntime(1829):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
07-07 11:12:09.500: E/AndroidRuntime(1829):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-07 11:12:09.500: E/AndroidRuntime(1829):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
07-07 11:12:09.500: E/AndroidRuntime(1829):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5039)
07-07 11:12:09.500: E/AndroidRuntime(1829):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-07 11:12:09.500: E/AndroidRuntime(1829):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
07-07 11:12:09.500: E/AndroidRuntime(1829):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
07-07 11:12:09.500: E/AndroidRuntime(1829):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
07-07 11:12:09.500: E/AndroidRuntime(1829):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-07 11:12:09.500: E/AndroidRuntime(1829): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: println needs a message
07-07 11:12:09.500: E/AndroidRuntime(1829):     at android.util.Log.println_native(Native Method)
07-07 11:12:09.500: E/AndroidRuntime(1829):     at android.util.Log.v(Log.java:117)
07-07 11:12:09.500: E/AndroidRuntime(1829):     at com.example.g2k.HotelSearch.onCreate(HotelSearch.java:22)
07-07 11:12:09.500: E/AndroidRuntime(1829):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
07-07 11:12:09.500: E/AndroidRuntime(1829):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
07-07 11:12:09.500: E/AndroidRuntime(1829):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
07-07 11:12:09.500: E/AndroidRuntime(1829):     ... 11 more
07-07 11:12:14.430: E/Trace(1848): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
```

Source code:

```
public class HotelBook extends Activity {
private String resp;

private ProgressDialog pDialog;

// Creating JSON Parser object
JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();

ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> hotelsList;
HashMap<String, String> map;
// JSON Node names
private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
private static final String TAG_HOTEL = "hotels";
private static final String TAG_PID = "hotel_id";
private static final String TAG_NAME = "hotel_name";
private static final String TAG_AREA = "area";
private static final String TAG_RATING = "star_rating";
private static final String TAG_IMAGE = "image";
private static final String TAG_GOVRATE = "govrating";
private static final String TAG_PRICE = "price";

private String city_id = "feedbacktype2";
// products JSONArray
JSONArray hotels = null;

Button sendPostReqButton;
private static final String url = "http://10.0.2.2/android_connect/search_hotel.php";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_hotelbook);
    // Hashmap for ListView
    hotelsList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

    StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder()
            .permitAll().build();
    StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
    sendPostReqButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    addListenerOnButton();
}

public void addListenerOnButton() {

    sendPostReqButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // Get the data
            // Loading products in Background Thread
            new GetHotel().execute();
        }

    });

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_hotelbook, menu);
    return true;
}

class GetHotel extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        /*
         * pDialog = new ProgressDialog(HotelbookActivity.this);
         * pDialog.setMessage("Loading hotels. Please wait...");
         * pDialog.setIndeterminate(false); pDialog.setCancelable(false);
         * pDialog.show();
         */
    }

    protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
        // Building Parameters
        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("cityid", city_id));

        // getting JSON string from URL
        JSONObject json = null;
        try {
            json = jParser.makeHttpRequest(url, "GET", params);
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            // Check your log cat for JSON reponse
            Log.e("All hotels: ", e1.toString());
        }

        // Check your log cat for JSON reponse
        Log.d("All hotels: ", json.toString());

        try {
            // Checking for SUCCESS TAG
            int success = 1;
            // json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

            if (success == 1) {
                // products found
                // Getting Array of Products
                hotels = json.getJSONArray(TAG_HOTEL);

                // looping through All Products
                for (int i = 0; i < hotels.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject c = hotels.getJSONObject(i);

                    // Storing each json item in variable
                    String id = c.getString(TAG_PID);
                    String name = c.getString(TAG_NAME);
                    String area = c.getString(TAG_AREA);
                    String rating = c.getString(TAG_RATING);
                    String image = c.getString(TAG_IMAGE);
                    String price = c.getString(TAG_PRICE);
                    String govrate = c.getString(TAG_GOVRATE);
                    // creating new HashMap
                    map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                    // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                    map.put(TAG_PID, id);
                    map.put(TAG_NAME, name);
                    map.put(TAG_AREA, area);
                    map.put(TAG_RATING, rating);
                    map.put(TAG_IMAGE, image);
                    map.put(TAG_PRICE, price);
                    map.put(TAG_GOVRATE, govrate);

                    // adding HashList to ArrayList
                    hotelsList.add(map);
                }

            } else {

            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("response error", json.toString(), e);
        }

        return null;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {

        Intent intent = new Intent(HotelBook.this, HotelSearch.class);
        intent.putExtra("map", map);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}

}
```

JSONParser class:

```
public class JSONParser {

InputStream is = null;
JSONObject jObj = null;
static String json = "";

// constructor
public JSONParser() {

}

// function get json from url
// by making HTTP POST or GET method
public JSONObject makeHttpRequest(String url, String method,
        List<NameValuePair> params) throws IOException {

    // Making HTTP request
    try {

        // check for request method
        if (method == "POST") {
            // request method is POST
            // defaultHttpClient
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
            httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));

            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            is = httpEntity.getContent();

        } else if (method == "GET") {
            // request method is GET
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            String paramString = URLEncodedUtils.format(params, "utf-8");
            url += "?" + paramString;
            HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);

            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            is = httpEntity.getContent();
        }

    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }

        json = sb.toString();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
    } finally {
        is.close();
    }

    // try parse the string to a JSON object
    try {
        jObj = new JSONObject(json);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
    }

    // return JSON String
    return jObj;

}

}
```

Comment: show your source code. main activity code. It seems that you want network operation on main activity thread which is not allowed in android. Network operation can be used by using AsyncTask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your logcat points a finger to HotelbookActivity.java line 154, where you perform operation on `null`ed object:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
07-05 08:36:07.533: E/AndroidRuntime(1073): at
        com.example.go2kashmir.HotelbookActivity$GetHotel
        .doInBackground(HotelbookActivity.java:154)
```

**EDIT**

If as you said line 154 is around `json` access, then this line:

```
Log.d("All hotels: ", json.toString());
```

should log:

```
All hotels: null
```

to confirm that (and explicit `toString()` is not needed in this case). Log raw response your `jParser`'s `makeHttpRequest()` do to see what really server returns. Problem lurks around there.

Comment: thanks,but i am not able to track which return call is causing NullPointerException , i am a newbie to android pardon me.

Comment: We are rather not going to guess which line is 154, so if you want help you need to tell us that

Comment: line 154.    if (success == 1) {
   hotels = json.getJSONArray(TAG_HOTEL);

Comment: it means your json Object "Hotels" is empty. run your php script on local to check what json is returning.

Comment: After running the php script on local server , it is returning the hotels array correctly , After further looking in logcat ,have realized that activity is not able to establish connection with my local server "http://127.0.0.1/android_connect/search_hotel.php" , is there any problem in host address?

Comment: Thanx, After changing my url to "http://10.0.2.2/****" it is able to receive response and as you suggested logging json object in logcat , is showing array fetched from server in logcat but still some exceptions are occuring and m not able to display that array in my other activity that i am passing through hashmap in intent....??

Comment: now logcat says                                                  07-07 10:26:04.131: E/AndroidRuntime(1521): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.g2k/com.example.g2k.HotelSearch}: java.lang.NullPointerException: println needs a message
07-07 10:26:04.131: E/AndroidRuntime(1521):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
07-07 10:26:04.131: E/AndroidRuntime(1521):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)

Answer (score 0):

You are not using the log function as intended.  The first argument is supposed to identify the context, while the message should be the second argument.

Instead, do something like

```
Log.d("MyActivity", "Object of interest is " + objectOfInterest);
```

That way, if the object is null you will get a log message saying so, instead of an exception.